# Access error in case of compilation of hadoop of the program

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, compilation, classpath

I tried to compile the hadoop-program by means of a command

```
root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin# ./javac -classpath /export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar;/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar -d /folder/classes /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java
```

also I received as a result the following messages

```
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use a help for a list of possible options
bash: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar: Permission denied
```

and it occurs without looking that the owner `/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar` is `root`, on it the maximum rights, and the `/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java` file really are set exists (this note about a line `javac: no source files`). Explain how to eliminate an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a colon (:) to separate path elements on unix systems - a semi colon denotes the a delimitation between commands, try this:

```
root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin# ./javac -classpath \
  /export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar \
  -d /folder/classes /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java
```